# Norwegian language character not showing proper in UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Norwqgian character in my unity project..
my code is:-

```
    void OnGUI()
    {
            style=new GUIStyle();
            style.fontSize=30;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),"Å gjøre seg klar   Når du                     har ",style);

    }
```

the output is 
[image]

it look like this..
The top dot of first character is not proper ...

can any one tell what is problem..?How I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue..
By using  **Lato**  font..
It shows Norwegian language character properly

Answer (score 0):

Both dots are like that, maybe its because you're not giving it enough space to put it over the letter? Try putting the `rect` a bit more spaced from the top.

Comment: no its not issue of space.
I have changed the co-ordinate of rectangle...
yet not solve...

Comment: Did you try changing the font? Maybe that font is just like that.

Comment: I have not apply any font here..its default

Comment: I know, maybe the default font it's like that. Try another one.

Comment: I tried with two different font,and in font inspector window set Character property to Unicode, The dot was ok, But it was not showing
å character...

not getting anything...

Comment: å character is disappearing

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe your problem could be on the font that you are using, if you are not using any font Unity uses a default (I think its Areal), try importing a new font that you know it actually writes the characters that you need.